# Reading file from HDFS using HDFS Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Hi am trying to read a file from HDFS using the Java API.

Connecting to HDFS and listing the files are working fine.

But while trying to read a file am getting the follow exception

Function call : fs.copyToLocalFile(path, dPath);

```
java.io.IOException: Could not obtain block: blk_-747325769320762541_16269493 file=/user/s3t.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSClient.java:2266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSClient.java:2060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.read(DFSClient.java:2221)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1203)
    at Access.main(Access.java:59)
```

**Note: Am able to create new files using fs.createNewFile(myPath);**

Comment: Are you able to get the file using `hadoop dfs -get`? I think the block is corrupted.

Comment: yes i am able to get the file using "hadoop dfs -get".

Comment: That is strange, because `dfs -get` uses exactly the same API. Can you recheck if you were accessing the same file? Are you running the java program as the same user?

Comment: Yeah am accessing the same file. Actually am trying to access a remote HDFS and i am not running as any specific user. Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can check that in two ways.

1. check the permissions of the file, user and group of the file and your user and group, you must have the permissions to access the file.
2. As you are accessing the file remotly it might be the network path issue.

Please check the both.

Comment: the permissions are not a problem. will check the network path.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661092/5797400 - This might help. It's my solution to the `could not obtain block: BlockMissingException`.
Here's the essential points of the link:

1. Namenode does NOT directly read or write data.
2. Client (your Java program using Direct access to HDFS) interacts with Namenode to update HDFS namespace and retrieve block locations for reading/writing.
3. Client interacts directly with Datanode to read/write data.