# Timeout error when trying to connect to hadoop datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari

I'm getting this error when trying to putfile into hdfs.

```
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while 
waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : 
java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.1.1.14:50010]
```

I've looked up solutions and I see that you need to add this property to hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I'm using ambari to manage my hadoop services. How to add the property without it resetting to defaults after I restart hdfs on ambari? I am on a single node cluster running HDP 2.6.1.0.

Update: Managed to add properties to hdfs-site.xml

```
  <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>


  <property>
      <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

However, I am still getting the same Timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in hdfs site xml

```
<property> 
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
   <value>file:/path/to/hadoop/namenode</value> 
 </property> 

 <property> 
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
   <value>file:/path/to/hadoop/datanode</value> 
 </property>
```

Comment: My properties are already set
     <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/namenode,/mnt/resource/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>
 <property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/data,/mnt/resource/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>

Should they be something different?

Comment: How did you installed hadoop , and whats your configuration.

Comment: second, try hdfs dfs - ls . or hadoop fs -ls /  and see if these are working fine or not?  one more thing can you describe your cluster configuration

Comment: Everything is running fine from within the cluster. The problem is when I'm accessing from an outside IP, I get the timeout error when attempting to putfile.

Comment: For your last comment, this should not be a hadoop issue, it is looking more of a networking and permission issue. maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307235/reading-remote-hdfs-file-with-java will help.